# pandas multiindex with expanding window function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe, an example can be created using:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar','baz', 'baz','baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 
'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'qux','qux', 'qux'],
        [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
values = [1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second']), 
columns = ['test'])
```

resulting in a dataframe that looks like this

```
             test 
first   sec
bar     1   1
        2   1
        3   2
        4   2
        5   2
baz     1   1
        2   1
        3   1
        4   1
        5   1
foo     1   2
        2   2
        3   2
        4   3
        5   3
qux     1   3
        2   2
        3   2
        4   2
        5   2
```

I would like to figure out how to get the cumulative sum of the numbers in "test" for all "first" in a new column called ['result'].  I feel like I am close using

```
df['result'] = df.test.expanding(1).sum()
```

but I cannot figure out how to cut it off at df['sec'] = 5 and start again (it just keeps going)

I would like my final output to look like

```
             test  result
first   sec
bar     1   1      1   
        2   1      2
        3   2      4
        4   2      6
        5   2      8
baz     1   1      1
        2   1      2
        3   1      3
        4   1      4
        5   1      5
foo     1   2      2
        2   2      4
        3   2      6
        4   3      9
        5   3      12
qux     1   3      3
        2   2      5
        3   2      7
        4   2      9
        5   2      11
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How about `df['result'] = df.groupby(['first'])['test'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum())`

Comment: stellar, please post in result so that I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did this work, 
`df['result'] = df.groupby(['first'])['test'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum())`